# replace values in a float with a string- python

Tags: python

I wanted to replace dot in a float with a string

for example if I have a float 15.444 I need print it something like below 15 eggs 444 chicken

If take I take a real example,here is the code

```
enter code here

name = "chris"
height_cm = 175
height = (height_cm * 1/2.54) * 1/12 
weight = 79


print "He is %s" % name
print "His height is %.2f" %height, "inches" 
print "His weight is %d" % weight
```

the second print line will give the output "my height is 5.7 inches" here how do I replace "." with a string. In this case I need to replace the "." with a string "feet"

++++++++++++++++++output++++++++++++++++++++++++
He is chris
His height is 5.7 inches 
His weight is 79
+++++++++++++++++++output+++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: Try doing the problem before posting it. We will not write code for you.

Comment: What have you tried? This site requires you to show what you have tried and to explain how it did not work.

Comment: Convert it to string, split it on dot . If you face any problems after you try this, ask for help here.

Comment: You might be better off busy not storing it as a float in the first place, unless that's unavoidable.

Comment: @Eli sorry I'm new this site and newbie in coding, updated the question with what I have tried.

Comment: @Kris, read about https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace if you want to replace '.' with feet. Read about https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split if you want to split it on '.' and get the number before and after decimal.

Comment: @SilentMonk thanks a lot. Let me check the mentioned links

Answer (score -2):

I don't code python but you may want to do something along the line of this(java):

```
float input = 15.444f;
int[] split = (input+"").split(".");
System.out.println(split[0]+" eggs and "+split[1]+" chickens");
```

But why would you ever need to do something like this. A float is a horrible method of storage for 2 integer values. Try using an array instead.

Comment: The OP has tagged the question as "Python". So he wants the answer in Python.

Comment: Additionally, this isn't even valid java.